# Hostname does not show up in router?

Tags: networking

There are two machines:

1. Ubuntu Desktop (15.04) which connect to `WLAN`. Get `IP` from `dhcp server` (router). `hostname` shows up in the router properly. This machine uses `Network Manager`.
2. Ubuntu Server (14.04) which connect to `WLAN`. Has static `IP`. `hostname` DOES NOT show up in the router at all. This machine DOES NOT use `Network Manager`.

Both machines have been configured to have `DNS server`. For Ubuntu Desktop `DNS Server` is on `127.0.1.1` and for Ubuntu Server is on `127.0.0.1`. Both machine have `hostname` file containing their hostname.

I have read almost all posts related to this issue in `askubuntu` and some other sites, but still no hostname in the router for Ubuntu Server?

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
wpa-scan_ssid 0
address 192.168.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.0.0.0
broadcast 192.0.0.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: did you set the hostname option in your interface setup.

Comment: I did ,but it did not work.

Comment: Your server has a static IP and therefore he doesn't get the IP from the router. Which router you use?

Comment: could you add to the question the relevant lines of your interface configuration file

Comment: @A.B. it is Huawei E5377. If I set up to get IP from router (DHCP), still there is no hostname.

Comment: Your DNS is 192.168.1.1 and not 127.0.x.1

Comment: If I put 127.0.1.1 , then the DNS server cache does not work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The router gets your hostname from the dhcp request. If the interface is set to static it never makes this request.

A way of getting static ip address and use dhcp requests at the same time is to

- set a static ip address for the machine on the router and
- use dhcp for your interface

```
    auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
      wpa-scan_ssid 0
      hostname myhostname
```

Comment: It might work in the way you say, but I can not use it , because there is no entry in the router to set a static ip. If I set up Ubuntu server not to have static ip , there is no hostname as well.

Comment: I just check it just a few moment ago, it looks like , when it sets on DHCP, the hostname shows up.  I accept your answer though I can not use it. Is there any other way to make that request in another way?

Comment: Thank you, I spent almost 2 days trying to find out why my router wasn't detecting resolving my hostname. I had to edit my `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file to allow hostname sharing on DHCP requests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SAMBA...as soon as you do, then your Ubuntu hostname will be resolvable from a Windows or Linux client. This will def work for DHCP configured system...less certain for fixed IP.

Comment: How can samba help in this situation? The problem is that the host doesn't use DHCP, and thus does not send a hostname to the dhcp server, which can be included in the DNS server of said router...

Comment: Often wondered the same thing. Not sure exactly which part of Samba is responsible for it, but the hostname is often not resolvable unless samba is installed.
Worth a try....

Comment: The part that is responsible for this is the Windows Internet Name Service, or wins. The accepted answer is the *correct* solution.

Comment: This worked for me, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS